# Targeting localhost (ASP.NET) from real device (Flutter)

Tags: asp.net, flutter

I develop flutter app, and I debug it on real device, I tried many ways how to connect to localhost but I cant achieve that. One guy wrote enable isolation in router settings but my router doesnt have that option. Does anyone have idea what can be problem here?
I tried to target address http://192.168.1.250, http://192.168.1.250:51347, but nothing happens

Kind regards